# Unity tile palette empty 2018.1.0f2

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to use the tilemap system in 2018.1.0f2. I have dragged in my sprites, sliced them and made tiles for them, however when I go to drag them into a new palette nothing is displayed just an empty grid system.

Any suggestions would be great.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having the same problem. Also had a palette working last week. When I reopen Unity, it is blank.

After some research, this seems to be a bug in 2018.1. Experts are saying use 2017.4 for the time being, or you can always try the 2018.2 beta.

Good luck.

Comment: I have just tested with 2017.4.2f2 and the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem in 2018.1.1f1
Installing the latest beta solved the issue.